# Yet another Could not find generator rspec:install with ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I am having trouble getting rspec installed.  I added to my gem file:

```
group :test, :development do
gem 'rspec-rails','~> 2.0'
end
```

ran

```
bundle install
gem install rspec-rails
rails generate rspec:install
```

and received

```
Could not find generator rspec:install.
```

The gem shows up under gem list, but not in bundle install.  I have been googling this error and none of the solutions worked for me.  I've tried different entries in my gem file.  I've updated my gem.  I have the current version of bundler.  I've tried

```
gem install rspec-rails --pre
```

and I've tried

```
rspec -v
```

which works

I am out of ideas.  Do any of you have any?

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out!  It was as simple as being in the wrong gemfile!  So embarrassing

Answer (score 1):

Nothing worked for me until I commented out these gems in my gemfile:

```
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',          group: :doc
gem 'spring',        group: :development
```

Finally back in business. :)

Answer (score 1):

It could be because another rails environment is running.  Do

```
spring stop
```

from the command line then try it again.  This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

In your **application.rb** file, just add the following configuration.

```
config.generators do |g|
  g.test_framework  :rspec
end
```

and now try to run the following command

```
rails generate rspec:install
```